# How to do own JWPlayer skin?

Tags: javascript, xml, jwplayer

I want to do my own jwplayer6 skin. I found some tutorials on official pages, but it doesn't work for me. I gues, I have a mistake somewhere. I found that I have to do my own XML file where I have to define the skin. I download custom jwplayer6 skin in XML format and I edit it and link into my script on my webpages. The source is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="LJ2OdmUWFU9huxlX+xQ47geW5DeqsVTFce3RZg==";</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "song.mp3",
        skin: "skin/six.xml"
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I edited [the original XML](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/sdks/jw6-skin-sdk/skins/six) to do some changes in skin, but it didn't work, so I totally deleted all unneeded XML tags, but the player is still the same, so I haven't got any idea, how to make my own skin. Any idea? Here is the [live preview](http://metalista.cz/jwplayer/player.html).

Comment: It seems to be loading the skin fine for me?

Comment: And it is wrong. The XML is totally empty, so the skin, shouln't be loading fine. If I changed some properties in XML the skin is loading still in the same way.

Comment: if the skin doesn't load, it just loads the default skin instead.

Comment: No problem, any time.